# Зачем нужен const в сигнатуре метода класса?

Tags: c++

Что означает `const` в данном случае?

```
class Person
{
    int age;
public:
    void display() const
    {
        cout << "тут что-то выводим " << age << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это означает, что функция не изменяет сам объект (за исключением членов данных объекта класса, объявленных со спецификатором `mutable`, которые можно менять даже в функциях, объявленных с квалификатором `const`), для которого она вызвана.

Поэтому эту функцию вы можете вызывать, например, для константных объектов:

```
const Person person = { 18 };

person.display();
```

Или

```
void f( const Person &person )
{
    person.display();
}

//...

Person person = { 18 };

f( person );
```

То есть вгутри этой функции указатель на объект `this` имеет тип `const Person *`

Имейте в виду, что определение класса должно завершаться точкой с запятой:

```
class Person
{
//...
};
^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте почитать книгу **Роберта Лафоре**. Там это очень прекрасно описано :)

В двух словах примерно так: Объект, который вы создадите, не сможет поменять данные через этот метод.

```
class Person
{
public:
int age;
void display() const
    {
        cout<<"тут что-то выводим"<<age<<endl;
    }
}
```

Вот, например, я добавлю пару методов к вашему классу.

```
class Person
{
private:
  int age;
public:
  void input (int new_age)
  {
    age = new_age; // передали какое-то значение.
  }
  void display(int new_age) const
  {
    age = new_age; // ПРИ КОМПИЛЯЦИИ ВЫЙДЕТ ОШИБКА, ПОТОМУ ЧТО МЕТОД КОНСТАНТНЫЙ. ЭТО ОЗНАЧАЕТ ЧТО ВНУТРИ ЭТОГО МЕТОДА Я НЕ МОГУ МЕНЯТЬ ПОЛЯ КЛАССА.
  }
}
```