# Зачем нужен const в сигнатуре функции?

Tags: c++, классы, функции, const

Например, у меня есть следующий код.

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;  
class X {  
 int x;  
public:  
 X(int i = 2): x {i} {}  

 void print() const {cout << x;}  
 //           ^^^^^
 int getx() const {return x;} 
 //         ^^^^^
 X operator-(const X& rop) {return x + 2*rop.x;} 
 //          ^^^^^ 
 int operator-(int rop) {return 2*x + rop;}

}; 

int operator-(int lop, const X& rop) {
//                     ^^^^^
 return lop – rop.getx();
}  



int main() {  
 X x {6},y;  
 cout << x – 3 – y;  
 return 0;  
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каково назначение ключевого слова `const` в сигнатуре функций?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем нужен const в сигнатуре метода класса?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445545/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-const-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Чтобы этот код мог работать с константными объектами. Это `const` означает, что вызов метода `print()` не изменит состояния объекта.

```
void print() const {cout << x;}  
int getx()   const {return x;}
```

Здесь вы никак не меняете объект класса - поэтому нет никакого смысла делать НЕ `const` (мое мнение - лучше делать все, что только можно, с `const`, применяя его по умолчанию, и **не** использовать его только там, где это необходимо), зато эти методы можно будет вызвать, например, при передаче объекта в качестве константного параметра - вот как тут:

```
X operator-(const X& rop) {return x + 2*rop.x;}
```

Вы же никак не меняете `rop`, так что можете теперь вызывать оператор для любого объекта, в том числе временного.

Кстати, операторы я бы тоже делал константными, типа

```
X operator-(const X& rop) const {return x + 2*rop.x;}
```

поскольку они никак не меняют состояние объекта.

Comment: Бинарные операторы лучше вообще делать свободными функциями.

Comment: @Harry объясните значение слов `Здесь вы никак не меняете объект класса - поэтому нет никакого смысла делать НЕ const`

Comment: @perfect const ставим всегда, если нет причины его не ставить

Comment: @perfect Именно - const ставлю по умолчанию. Грубо говоря, мне даже кажется, что логичнее было бы вводить модификатор `nonconst` :)

Comment: @Harry. просто мне кажется разумным написать `Здесь вы никак не меняете объект класса - поэтому делаем const` . а то `НЕ const` меня вводит в ступор )

Comment: @Harry ... и насчет nonconst если вам не хватает этого слова тогда просто напишите этот пустой макрос

Comment: @perfect Бессмысленно, потому что на отсутствие `const` макрос не пропишешь :)

Comment: @Harry http://cpp.sh/2vxiq

Comment: @perfect и чем Ваш макрос будет лучше, чем его полное отсутствие?

Comment: @Harry в лямбдах вот кстати `const` по умолчанию подразумевается, а для модификаций надо добавлять `mutable`.

Comment: @alexolut почитайте комментарии harry , nonconst которое он очень хочет (а по мне так это больше философия чем программирование) это и есть его отсутствие

Comment: @perfect он хочет чтобы `const` был неявный, а Вы ему явный `nonconst` предлагаете. Почувствуйте разницу.

Comment: @alexolut да чувствую ненужную разницу (для меня). столько ненужной возни получится.

Answer (score 5):

Нестатическая функция-член, помимо явно указанных в круглых скобках параметров, принимает еще и неявный указатель `this`. Т.е. указатель на экземпляр объекта, на котором эта функция была вызвана.

Если `const` после списка параметров не указан `this` имеет тип `X* const`, т.е. указатель, который нельзя поменять, но сам объект изменять можно через этот указатель.

А вот когда `const` присутствует, тип `this` становится `const X* const`, т.е. добавляется запрет на попытки изменить объект через этот указатель.

Наличие `const` для конкретного параметра функции говорит о том, что нельзя изменять именно этот параметр. Для других параметров будут действовать их собственные ограничения.

В общем случае, добавление `const` там, где объект не предполагается изменять позволяет писать более надёжный и понятный код, т.е. нельзя случайно изменить объект, который по логике разработчика меняться не должен. При попытке изменить такой объект, компилятор выдаст ошибку.

По теме `const` можно напомнить ещё о существовании ключевого слова `mutable`, наличие которого у члена объекта позволяет менять этот член даже если была вызвана `const` функция объекта.